# TFS 2012 + Visual studio 2012: some settings options return "The user name or password is incorrect"

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

I've upgraded our TFS 2010 to TFS 2012 without any issues. I can connect to the source control, checkin, everything I need to Work.

But if I go to the settings page for the team project I'm connected to, the following options **work** as expected:

Team project: Source Control

Team project: Portal settings

Team Project Collection: Source Control

Team Project Collection: Process Template Manager

But the rest of the options on the settings page just gives me this error

[image: tfs error]

I've tried looking at the requests Visual Studio makes to the TFS server using Fiddler, and with the ones that **don't** work, no requests are actually being made to the server. So it seems like the server is never being contacted for those specific options.

I've tested this on two independent installations of Visual studio 2012, runnning on Windows 8.

**EDIT**

I just installed VS2010 SP1 on one of the machines, and I can just fine access all of the following settings options: Security, Group Membership, Areas and Iterations, Portal Settings and Source Control.

Looks like a VS2012 issue of some sort.

Comment: I noticed all of the options that you state do not work are the ones where the options are modified in a web browser.  What happens if you open your browser to http://<your-tfs-server>/tfs/<your-collection-likley-DefaultCollection>/_admin/_security

Comment: @EdHintz I tried that specific url and it worked fine, also haven't found any other setting pages of web access not working.

Comment: I've got the same issue with a brand new install of TFS 2012 and VS 2012 cleanly installed on all of our workstations. Tried running VS 2012 as Administrator but that did not work as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We resolved our issue with this by running VS 2012 with our domain credentials. We use VMs for development, so we do not directly login into the domain. To run VS, we use the following (as a batch file):

runas /netonly /user: username "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

where username is your domain credential.

Comment: Works just as excepted, although somewhat annoying

Comment: We just recently resolved our issue regarding this by adding our development virtual machines to the domain. This seems to completely resolve this issue as well.

Comment: Verified working, but as @Xorandor mentioned, it's a bit annoying :)  But since I leave VS open 99% of the time, typing in my password isn't that big of a deal I guess.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the code is still using some values that are cached on the client after the upgrade. How long ago was it that you upgraded the server?

To test whether that is it, rename your cache folder (with VS 2012 closed) and launch VS 2012 again so it recreates the cache from scratch.

C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\4.0