# Team Foundation Error: The user name or password is incorrect

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I am connected to the TFS server and can view the Source Control Explorer, check out/check in, create new projects, etc.  However, when I try to access some options from the Team Explorer menu like "settings > security" or even "Web Access" I get a popup that says "The user name or password is incorrect".

Please note that I can manually go to servername:8080/tfs and everything works fine.

Comment: Check this answer on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12328422/1132131

Comment: What happens if you add your credentials to the Windows Credential Manager?  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/what-is-credential-manager

Comment: Nailed it @TimVK, not sure how I missed it in a search.  Voted to close as duplicate.