# I can check-in new added files but can't check-in edited files

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs, version-control

I have a strange problem about Visual Studio 2015 and TFS.

I have successfully added source control to my project. After that I made the first check-in . Everything was as expected. After making any change in the one of the project file, I wanted to check-in again.

But visual studio gives the following error: **"The user name or password is incorrect."**

My colleague can get the project from TFS, make changes on the file and check-in successfully.

Also I am not able to get the latest version of any file from the source control. This operation also gives the same error.

I can also login to web panel. My username and password is correct.

Does anyone encountered a problem like that? How can I solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the username/password stored in the Windows Credential Manager.

Comment: @jessehouwing I checked the stored data in the Windows Credential Manager. It is correct. I can check in the newly created file already. Can't check-in the edited file.

Comment: Are you able to edit file and check in on web portal?

Comment: @Cece-MSFT Yes I am able to do anything on web portal. It works as expected. But there is something wrong with visual studio and TFS.

Answer (score 0):

Try to clean the cache folder on your client computer. The folder path is: `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`.

Also, try the solution in this case [TFS 2012 + Visual studio 2012: some settings options return "The user name or password is incorrect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12328422/tfs-2012-visual-studio-2012-some-settings-options-return-the-user-name-or-pa) by running VS with your domain credentials.

Comment: I did clear the cache folder but it didn't work. I enter my credentials when the visual studio prompt for the tfs. But still no luck. I also run the command at the link but still the error remains. That is a really weird problem. I just can't check-in the edited files or get any file from the tfs.

Comment: If you use your account on another client machine, will you get this error?

Comment: I didn't try that but I believe that my account is not the problem here. Because I am able to check-in new files to tfs. Also my colleague gave me the administration right to get over the security restrictions but error is still there.

Comment: I believe your account is not problem as you can do anything on web portal. But you may try on another machine to see whether server side store your credential, and clean the cache folder on server machine C:\TfsData\ApplicationTier\_fileCache.